# Use different profile image sizes in Microsoft Graph Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-toolkit

In my MGT React SharePoint WebPart, I would like to have some of the profile images displayed with large size (48px), while other images displayed with medium size (36px).

I know the property avatarSize can be used, but this only supports Small, Large or Auto. And in the mgt-person css class, I can specify --avatar-size: 36px. But since this css class affects all person components on the page, all profile images are now sized 36px. And there is no support for specifying a css class on the person component itself.

Do you know if this can be achieved another way?

UPDATE:
I managed to solve this myself with the help from this article:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/a-lap-around-microsoft-graph-toolkit-day-4-customizing-components/

Using the following definitions in my scss file, it can adjust the avatar size based on for example a WebPart property:

```
  .personsmall mgt-person {
    --avatar-size: 24px;
  }
  .personmedium mgt-person {
    --avatar-size: 36px;
  }
  .personlarge mgt-person {
    --avatar-size: 48px;
  }
```

And in my tsx file, it looks like this:

```
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IRolesProps> {
    let cf: CommonFunctions = new CommonFunctions();

    return (
      <div className={this._getAvatarSizeClass(this.props.roleSize)}>
        {this.props.roles && this.props.roles.map((val) => {
          return (
            <Stack className={styles.roleSpacing}>
              <Text className={styles.roleHeader} variant="xLarge">{val.role}</Text>
              <Person userId={val.person} view=PersonViewType.twolines fetchImage={true} showPresence={true}
                personCardInteraction={PersonCardInteraction.hover} line2Property="mail"></Person>
            </Stack>);
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

  private _getAvatarSizeClass(avatarSize: AvatarSize): any {
    if (avatarSize) {
      switch (avatarSize) {
        case AvatarSize.Small:
          return styles.personsmall;
        case AvatarSize.Medium:
          return styles.personmedium;
        case AvatarSize.Large:
          return styles.personlarge;

        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps someone else struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a styling guide: [MGT Styling guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/style)

You can simply create a CSS rule and call the desired component. Example from the styling guide

```
mgt-person {
  --avatar-size: 34px;
}
```

Thus you should be able to combine this with a CSS class such as:

```
mgt-person.my-avatar-size {
  --avatar-size:42px;
}
```

Since all [React components](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) expose a `className` attribute this should work:

`<Person className='my-avatar-size'></Person>`

*UPDATE*

Since, for some reason, there is no `className` attribute available, why don't you use a `data-` attribute instead:

```
mgt-person[data-cssclass='my-avatar-size']{
  --avatar-size:42px;
}
```

`<Person data-cssclass='my-avatar-size'></Person>`

Hacky, but should work. Also, you might want to look at the actual generated HTML and use this.

Comment: I tried that, but it complains that Person does not contain this property. I've tried className="my-avatar-size", class="my-avatar-size" and className={styles.my-avatar-size}. None of them works.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. But I resolved it, and updated my initial question with a working example. Thank you very much for your help.